# Some members are not showing in Visual Studio 2013 Object Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, msdn

I have Googled this question, but didn't find any appropriate answer.

I have searcher for `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` in VS2013's `Object Browser` and then in `MSDN`.

**Object Browser result**

[image: Object Browser Results]

---

**MSDN Result**

---

[image: MSDN Results]

---

You can see `MSDN` is showing a big list of methods but `Object Browser` shows only few of them.

My question is: Why some members are not showing in `Object Brower`? However, they are showing in `MSDN`.

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: Are you able to use MSDN ones in your code?

Comment: @UsmanFarooq it is shown for me, but I'm using Ultimate Edition.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I have just tried a MasterPage class's property `HasChildViewState` and its working fine.

`if (this.HasChildViewState)
 {
        //Some code
 }`. This property is not showing in Object Browser but its showing in `MSDN` and also in `Intellisense`.